# Sample size for a quantile estimator

Tags: probability, estimation, confidence-interval

Assume that I have a population of size $N$ with an attribute which is a continuous variable. Let's say these are people and the attribute is their height. I want to find the $90\%$ quantile of that population. But instead of calculating it from the entire population, I'd like to estimate it from a sample I take.

I think that taking the $90\%$ quantile of the sample will be the best estimator for the $90\%$ quantile of the population (correct me if I am wrong). How good is this estimation though? In other words what is the probability that the true quantile is at most $x\%$ away from the estimation? Or conversely, what should the sample size be so I can achieve a certain confidence in my estimation (e.g., I am within $10\%$ of the true value with probability $0.99$)

Comment: Can you assume the population is approximately normally distributed in this attribute? If not then this is a slightly more complicated statistics problem.

Comment: @Ian I cannot assume a normal distribution. But I'd be interested to know the solution for that special case.

Comment: You should try asking this question on [stats.se], where it may be a better fit.  In any case, there is a related problem of finding the _mean_ with guaranteed error tolerances in the sense of your last sentence, and there are [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158937) for that problem ([second](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/estimation.md)).  But finding a _quantile_ estimate with similar guarantees might be more difficult, especially because [no unbiased median estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36134) exists, for example.